# Dealing with userInput from AlertDialog on android Studio

Tags: java, android

Currently struggling to handle the user input from my AlertDialog box. Everything works fine, but I don't know what to do with the user input in order to save it and access it within another function.

```
private void promptUser() {
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText promptTitle = new EditText(this);
    promptTitle.setHint("Title");
    layout.addView(promptTitle);

    userPrompt = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    userPrompt.setView(layout);

    userPrompt.setTitle("Enter map information").setView(layout);
    userPrompt.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Log.i("AlertDialog", "Create button was hit");
            Log.i("AlertDialog", "This is the text that was entered:" + promptTitle.getText().toString());
            userInputs = promptTitle.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    userPrompt.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            Log.i("AlertDialog", "Cancel button was hit");
        }
    });

    userPrompt.show();
}
```

and where I call the function:

```
public void onMapClick( LatLng point ) {

    promptUser()
    //Log.d(userInputs.get(0), "COOL");

}
```

The main error I'm encountering is that after calling my method promptUser(), everything runs but the next several lines of code don't wait for the user to click the PositiveButton. e.g, my Log shows "User inputs: null", since tempString isn't yet available. How can I make my function wait until the user has hit submit before running the next line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Put the call to onMapClick inside the positive button callback.

```
userPrompt.setPositiveButton("Create", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        userInputs = promptTitle.getText().toString();
        onMapClick();
    }
});
```

It's a bit hard to tell if this is exactly what you want since you haven't provided enough code, but this is what you asked for.

Comment: Apologies. I'll edit with more code to show exactly what I'm trying to do.